# how to edit tree structured data with d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

```
let treeData = {
  "name": "Top Level",
  "parent": "null",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Level 2: A",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Son of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 2: B",
      "parent": "Top Level"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add children to "Level 2: B". I tried hierarchy function it is not helping me to update original treeData, so I could re render entire tree by appending children to a required node.

```
d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
  return d.children;
});
```

Result expected is

```
let treeData = {
  "name": "Top Level",
  "parent": "null",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Level 2: A",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Son of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 2: B",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "children": [
         {"name": "Level 3: C", 
          "parent": "Level 2: B"
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My requirement is to update original treeData with the help of d3 js. So, I can re render tree with updated treeData to see the latest data.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear: do you want to simply change the original object which is passed to the hierarchy generator or do you want to change the object created by the hierarchy generator?

Comment: I updated question with more details, I would like to update treeData(as mentioned in post) which passed to hierarchy generator.

Comment: In that case, why don't you just do `treeData.children[1].children = [{"name": "Level 3: C", "parent": "Level 2: B"}];`? Do you need anything more dynamic?

Comment: Ya, expecting a dynamic way.

Comment: In that case, *how*? We can only answer your question if we know what you want.

Comment: I can click a node, and will get an unique identifier(hash) of the clicked node. So, I can go to server with that hash and find the children of it and append as children to same node in treeData. After I will re render entire treeData with latest children additions.